# How to place two subfigures one above the other in the margin paragraph?

Tags: subfloats, marginpar, sidenotes

I want to create something like the following:

[image]

That is, place two graphics in the margin paragraph (I couldn't find a similar MWE in a search here on the website).

What I have at the moment is the following:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,geometry}
%%% Page layout
\geometry{%
left=15mm,
textwidth=130mm,
marginparsep=8.2mm,
marginparwidth=50mm,
showframe
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example images a and b.}
  %
  \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Caption for the second figure.}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

But this creates two separate figures.

What package should I use to create such sub-figures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subcaption` is what you need here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%%% Page layout
\geometry{%
left=15mm,
textwidth=130mm,
marginparsep=8.2mm,
marginparwidth=50mm,
showframe
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Caption image-a}
{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{Caption image-b}
{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Caption image-a \& b}

\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum[2-4]


\end{document}
```

Comment: You haven't missed anything. That is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @tush bevakasha !